# How to connect NXT brick to EV3 programming software for mac (2024)

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, electronics, ev3-g, mac

I have an NXT brick (most likely from 2006 based on a newspaper clipping I found in the box) that I want to program the NXT brick with the EV3 programming software (the newer version of the EV3 app for Windows 10+ and later mac versions). I read online that you could do this, but for some reason the EV3 software isn't recognizing the NXT brick that I have plugged in. Using macOS 12.7 and NXT screen is dead like a lot of NXTs.